# Rails 4 with Bootstrap 3 and Assets from fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Deal all,

I've copied all my bootstrap assets to app/assets. There are these folders:

```
-javascripts
-stylesheets
-images
-fonts
```

The JS and CSS is included like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

But now the glyphicons don't work because they were tried to load from /fonts/...

What should I configure to solve this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

> bootstrap-sass is easy to drop into Rails with the asset pipeline.
>
> In your Gemfile you need to add the bootstrap-sass gem, and ensure
>   that the sass-rails gem is present - it is added to new Rails
>   applications by default.
>
> ```
> gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
> gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
> ```
>
> bundle install and restart your server to make the files available
>   through the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to use [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem than copy/update assets by hands. It'll provide fonts as assets.